# get all the possible parameters of sql view

Tags: openlayers-2, postgis, geoserver, javascript

I have a Geoserver layer coming from a postGIS database. Among other attributes, I have one that is related to the date data we've collected, called `departuretime`. We use this attribute to display a layer on the map with Openlayers, by adding a layer with a GET request having a `viewparams` argument (we use a http protocol calling for a JSON and not a WFS because `viewparams` doesn't seem to be implemented in OL yet):

```
layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(date[i], {
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
    //options,
    url: "http://domain.com:8080/geoserver/test/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=test%3Av_trajectory&maxfeatures=50&outputformat=json&viewparams=departuretime:"+tmpDate+"T000000Z"
});
```

Since we will have in the end quite a lot of data distributed along a long period of days, I want to create a filter (via a datepicker) that displays only the layer of the selected days. Right now, I have something that works with the data we have, but the filter is hard coded into the JS, since I know what dates we have collected data. In the future, I want that if we add new data to the database, we can also add those, without modifying the JS script.

I couldn't find a way to query Geoserver so it returns me an array (or whatever) containing all possible values that departuretime can take. Is this possible, or do I have to create a new feature with a table containing the parameter?